# C# - check if list contains an object where a property equals value?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a shorthand way to do it that does not involve loops?

```
public enum Item { Wood, Stone, Handle, Flint, StoneTool, Pallet, Bench  }

public struct ItemCount
{
    public Item Item;
    public int Count;
}

private List<ItemCount> _contents;
```

so something like:

```
if(_contents.Contains(ItemCount i where i.Item == Item.Wood))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I was going to answer but the two below deserved and upvote. Linq.Any is the right solution.

Comment: Do you actually need the element? Or are you only doing lookups to see if it exists?

Comment: I was going to add to the list. So if it's not there it will add it; if it is there then it will increment the int property of the struct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need reflection, you can just use Linq:

```
if (_contents.Any(i=>i.Item == Item.Wood))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

If you need the object/s with that value, you can use `Where`:

```
var woodItems = _contents.Where(i=>i.Item == Item.Wood);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do this using `Linq` extension method `Any`.

```
if(_contents.Any(i=> i.Item == Item.Wood))
{
    // logic   
}
```

In case if you need a matching object, do this.

```
var firstMatch = _contents.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Item == Item.Wood);

if(firstMatch != null)
{
    // logic   
    // Access firstMatch  
}
```